# MacOS 12.5 file names are created with wrong char

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, encoding, utf-8

I made a script to rename mp3 files based on the tags, basically it extracts the data like this:

```
sArtist=$(exiftool -s3 -Artist "$sFile")
...
sNewName="$sArtist - $sTitle"
mv -v "${sFile}" "${sNewName}.${sFileExt}"
```

The problem is with the diacritics, for example in the artist name, the character `á` in the filename is saved as unicode `aU+0301` while the expectation is that it should be saved as `U+00E1`

Any idea why?

Here is the output of env:

```
$ env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/zsh
TMPDIR=/var/folders/c5/38kntdc107jbxmc_8sg8_qfc0000gn/T/
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=445
TERM_SESSION_ID=BCFA74E2-4B36-447A-8DE8-4598EFB89474
USER=******
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HuUuhLPn6d/Listeners
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
_=/usr/bin/env
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
PWD=/
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
HOME=/Users/******
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=******
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.omquYUiZVj/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Comment: Which encoding is used in the EXIF tag?

Comment: Don't filenames go through a normalization step?